# How to stop a process and begin other process without returning to the initial Process in Arduino

Tags: algorithm, arduino, interrupt

I desire to construct a Hexapod which utilizes Arduino and is remotely controlled via Bluetooth, at present I am writing the code for its walking(in Arduino part),however I do not know how to proceed.The problem is as follow:
When a new command is received from the remote device I want the legs to stop what they are doing and carry out the received command.If this action is realized with Interrupts then after the command has been completed the previous process again starts,which is undesired for me. What can be done?
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

The arduino doesn't really have separate processes - or even an OS.

You should think in terms of "states". Have a global (sorry) int representing the current state (use an enum) then when you do a new command set the state to the new command and return, then have a main loop which checks the state and performs whatever function is needed.